# Test class for redirect controller

Tags: apex, unit-test

I need to create a test class for an apex controller which overrides the normal save function in my visualforce page and redirect the user to a custom page.

Can someone help me do this? I'm not sure what to test the controller on.

**Controller**

```
public class force_NewOrderLogic {

          ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
          public force_NewOrderLogic(ApexPages.StandardController con){
              stdController = con;
          }

public PageReference saveAndRedirect() {
  if(stdController.save() != null) {
    PageReference redirectPage = Page.force_OrderDetail;
    redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
    redirectPage.getParameters().put('id',stdController.getId());
    redirectPage.getParameters().put('msg','new-record-added');
    return redirectPage;
  } return null;
}

}
```

**UPDATE**:
**Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class test_NewOrderLogic {

    static testMethod void myTest() {

        PageReference pageRef = Page.force_OrderDetail;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        force_NewOrderLogic controller = new force_NewOrderLogic();
        String nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

        // Verify that page fails without parameters
        // System.assertEquals('/apex/failure?error=noParam', nextPage);


        // Verify that the success page displays
        System.assertEquals('/apex/force_OrderDetail', nextPage);
    }

}
```

I have attempted a very basic draft using some of the links provided in the answers, however I get the following error with the code above:

> Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [force_NewOrderLogic].() at line 9 column 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example [here](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm). The controller in the example also overrides the save function just like your requirement.

**UPDATE**

Because you set the constructor of the controller to accept a standard controller whenever you create a new instance of the force_NewOrderLogic controller you need to provide a standard controller in your test method.

These are the lines in your custom controller :

```
public force_NewOrderLogic(ApexPages.StandardController con){
              stdController = con;
}
```

So in your test method before creating a new instance of your custom controller you need to create an instance of the standard controller of the object you want to save:

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(your sobject here);
```

and pass it to your custom controller

```
force_NewOrderLogic controller = force_NewOrderLogic(sc);
```

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: Updated my answer